# How to convert array from mongodb database to string in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, mongodb

I have created a document in an MongoDB database and I wanted to show the results of the database on a web page with PHP on of the types of the properties of the document is an array that contains string. When I do show the connections this is what shows up

```
Name: Harry Anderson
Jersey 9
Position Array
```

The correct position should be "LF", "RF"

The PHP code I am using to get that result is

```
foreach ($cursor as $obj) {
echo "Name: ". $obj["name"]. "<br/>";
echo "Jersey ". $obj["jersey"]. "<br/>";
echo "Position ". $obj["position"]. "<br/>";
echo "<br/>";
}
```

I know that I am putting the position object incorrectly and it should be some indication of it being an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to `implode` the array:

```
foreach ($cursor as $obj) {
  echo "Name    : ".$obj["name"]."<br/>";
  echo "Jersey  : ".$obj["jersey"]."<br/>";
  echo "Position: ".implode(",", $obj["position"])."<br/>";
}
```

`implode(",", array)` will create a comma-separated list of all positions.

Answer (score 0):

Why not first store it as an array and then iterate over it?

```
$position = $obj["position"];
foreach ($position as $pos) {
    echo "Position: $pos<br/>";
}
```